# Двоеточие перед союзом и тире перед повелительным наклонением

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Перевожу субтитры к немому кино. Главный герой хочет обмануть взломщика и сымитировать убийство клиента, которого он должен защищать. Он говорит клиенту:

> Мы его одурачим: когда я выстрелю — упадите.

Правомочны ли тут двоеточие и тире?

Answer (score 4):

*Мы его одурачим: когда я выстрелю — упадите.*

Всё нормально. Двоеточие в БСП, потому что вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой: *Мы его одурачим* (как именно одурачим?)

Тире возможно, если придаточное времени находится в препозиции по отношению к главному.

Answer (score 4):

**Мы его одурачим: когда я выстрелю — упадите.**

Постановка тире связана скорее **с разной структурой предложений в СПП:**  главное предложение состоит из одного слова. (Это односоставное определенно-личное предложение, сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме повелительного наклонения).

Поэтому в таких предложениях делается пауза, которая обозначается тире, например: *Буде спросит кто о чём – молчи…*  Источник: http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect111

Сравнить: *Мы его одурачим: когда я выстрелю,  вы упадите.*

Comment: То есть, если фразу заканчивать "вы упадите", то ставится запятая, а если "упадите" - то тире?

Comment: Да, верно, здесь нет необходимости в применении такого сильного знака, как тире. Тире в СПП является дополнительным знаком, поэтому его применение желательно обосновать.